# XPath to get date from date picker

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the 1st active date from calendar,

```html
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ">
<span class="ui-state-default">18</span></td>
<td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2021">
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td>
```

In the example above 19 is the 1st active day. However I am not sure how to print that value. I have tried couple of things

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class='ui-state-default' and @href='#'])[1]")).getText()

                         OR

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//td[not(contains(@class,' ui-datepicker-unselectable '))]/..//a[@href])[1]")).getAttribute("innerText");
```

Both of those prints 2 and not 19. I want an xpath that will print the value 19

I could use some help here. Thank You.

Comment: Why the date month is data-month="4" ?

Comment: I think they started 0=Jan, 1=Feb so May is 4th.

Comment: Can I have the URL ?

Comment: Are you sure you get output as 2 and not a invalid xpath error?

Comment: @itronic1990 : xpath is not invalid, perhaps it is not correct.

Comment: @SheikhRahman you have an extra ")" before "[1]" in your xpaths which is causing org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector exception. Remove it to get the expected text from the element

Comment: @Sheikh Rahman can provide the whole table code can you check if the element not in the <frame>?
also, check if it does not overlap by any other element
just use the JavaScriptExecutor to return the innerText

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

String text = (String) js.executeScript(“return arguments[0].text;”, webl);

Answer (score 1):

The XPath to the text 19:

```
//td[@data-handler='selectDay']/a/text()
```

Comment: selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//td[@data-handler='selectDay']/a/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element

Comment: @SheikhRahman did you try: //td[@data-handler='selectDay']/a and then call getText() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath. Check if your element is not inside iframe or shadow DOM.

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-state-default' and  @href='#']")).getText();
```